# how to use variadic functions with functions as arguments and pass them to pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, variadic-functions

I am passing functions to function pointers

```
void tact::setFunctions(void short_press_function(void), void release_press_function(void), void long_press_function(void))
{
    short_ptr = short_press_function;
    release_ptr = release_press_function;
    long_ptr = long_press_function;
}
```

But these 3 pointers will not always be used in my programs. I want to use  a variadic function to pass a variable number of functions depending on which functionalities I turned ON.

```
    void tact::setFunctions(void args(), ...)

{

va_list ap;

va_start(ap, args);

#if SHORT_BUTTON_PRESS_CONFIG
    short_ptr = va_arg(ap, void (*)());
#endif
#if BUTTON_RELEASE_CONFIG   
    release_ptr = va_arg(ap, void (*)());
#endif
#if LONG_BUTTON_PRESS_CONFIG
    long_ptr = va_arg(ap, void (*)());
#endif

va_end(ap);

}
```

In this new function, I thing I did not understand correctly how to use va_arg(). I basically just want to pass the address of my arguments to my pointers. How?
Thanks!

Comment: That seems right. Except for the `void args()`. What problem are you seeing? In C, you always have to have one parameter before the variadic parameters. You could make it an `int` 0 for example.

Comment: Why are you using C-style varargs instead of a variadic template?

Comment: How are you going to use this function? Are you going to switch every call with the macros as well?

Comment: Probably pass noop function, or use different name for setFunction, one by member.